# Modifier key to change the action of the side scroll wheel on Logitech MX Master 3 mouse

Tags: macos, mouse, logitech-mouse

In macOS I currently have my Logitech MX Master 3 mouse set to "switch between desktops" when I roll the side scroll wheel. (I did this using the included Logi Options software). This is the way I like it, but I would like to be able to add additional functionality.

Is there a way to change the behavior of the side scroll wheel when I press a modifier key? For example, I would really like for the wheel to do horizontal scrolling when I hold the control key while side-scrolling.

Any tips/software recommendations would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep on wishing.
Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but the MXs are a nightmare because they hide the actual keycodes sent. I regret ever buying one. Standard 3rd party mouse control replacements, Steermouse, USB Overdrive etc cannot handle the extra scrollwheel or the gesture button. You can't even run Logitech's CP **and** one of the replacers, because they fight. You **can** run one of the replacers instead of the Logi, but you actually lose overall functionality.

You're stuck with whatever Logitech give you.

Comment: Shucks. What if I wanted to do the same thing except assign a modifier key to my regular vertical scroll wheel for horizontal scrolling. Would that be just as much of a pipe dream?

Comment: Shift-[main]scrollwheel is Mac standard for horizontal scroll. You should have no problems with that

Comment: In terms of overall usability, I ended up setting 'gesture button+plus drag right/left' to switch Spaces, & the side wheel to switch tabs [in browsers etc]. That ended up feeling the most ergonomic.

Comment: Woah -- I've owned a mac for 13 years... That is a good substitute.

Comment: I'm not sure when it was first introduced. Not a million years ago but a few years now. My first 3 or 4 macs didn't even have scrollwheels, & just one button ;-)

Comment: @Tetsujin 5+ year mac user, didn't know that 

Comment: This is very terrible,  configured keystrokes using Karabiner, buying the logic tech mx mouse messed everything up

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be only possible if you have *both* a Logitech Mouse *and* Logitech keyboard.

---

The mouse can be configured in great detail with the supplied Logi Options software. Your modifier key wish is called "Duolink" in the software. The modifier key is Fn in this case.

If desired, this can even be done individually for each application.

For example, I like it when the thumbwheel in the browser provides horizontal scrolling...

[image: thumbwheel in the browser provides horizontal scrolling]

...and then switches through the tabs with the Modifier Key, e.g. when I hold Fn.

[image: switches through the tabs with the Modifier Key]

Have fun with your MX Master, I do not know any better mouse until now.

Comment: How do you get that standard/duolink option? I don't have those buttons at all -- even though I am up to date with the latest version.

Comment: I use version 9.40.75. I did not do anything special. I connect via a receiver, not Bluetooth.

Comment: Weird -- I also use 9.40.75, and I connect via receiver rather than bluetooth as well.

Comment: @MichaelS. Do you use a Logitech keyboard with your mouse ? It seems that it's only available with logitech keyboard and mouse combo

Comment: Yes, I've never seen that standard/duolink option. I only have a Logitech mouse, Apple keyboard.

Comment: Can't find this on my logic option as well , I use a apple magic keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Just install the logitech options, the software allows you to configure you mouse as you like.
You can use the function of switch between desktops along with that you can setup custom settings for all the applications.